# Structure Delphi Generics Class

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-2010

I'm new to generics and need some help to structure a class and implement methods.

I'm trying to use generics to serialize *any* `TObject`-JSON. Moreover, I want to be able to reuse the code.

These are my questions:

1. How do I create a generic constructor? I want to be able to use `Self` or `Default(T)`, but it returns just `nil`.
2. `V := Marshal.Marshal(ReturnObject)` - This method requires a `TObject`, but I do not know how to reference the current object that was passed in.
3. How can I use this inside a method? Look at the code snipped below, marked with "*Question 3*".

This is my code:

```
TFileOperationResult = class(TObject)
private
  FSuccess: Boolean;
  //Error: PException;
  FLastError: Integer;
  function GetFailure: Boolean;
  property Failure: Boolean read GetFailure;
public
  property Success: Boolean read FSuccess write FSuccess;
  property LastError: Integer read FLastError write FLastError;
end;

TResponseObject<T: class> = class(TObject)
private
  FReturnObject: T;
  function GetReturnObject: T;
  function BaseStringsConverter(Data: TObject): TListOfStrings;
public
  constructor Create; overload;
  property ReturnObject: T read GetReturnObject;
  procedure Serialize;
end;

constructor TResponseObject<T>.Create;
begin
 // Question 1 - What should go in here?
end;

function TResponseObject<T>.GetReturnObject: T;
begin
  Result := Default(T);// Is this correct?
end;

procedure TResponseObject<T>.Serialize;
var
  Marshal: TJSONMarshal;
  V: TJSONValue;
begin
  Marshal := TJSONMarshal.Create(TJSONConverter.Create);
  Marshal.RegisterConverter(TResponseObject<T>, BaseStringsConverter);
  V := Marshal.Marshal(ReturnObject); // Question 2 - How Can I refer to 'Self'?
  OutPut := V.ToString;
  Marshal.Free;
end;
```

Calling code:

```
procedure TForm1.Test;
var
  FileOperationResult: TResponseObject<TFileOperationResult>;
begin
  FileOperationResult := TResponseObject<TFileOperationResult>.Create;
  FileOperationResult.Serialize;
end;
```

Question 3:

```
procedure TForm1.MoveCopyFile<THowNowResponse>(ASource, DDestination: String);
var
  FileOperationResult: TFileOperationResult;
begin
  FileOperationResult := TFileOperationResult.Create;
  // What to do?
end;
```

Any other comments are much appreciated.

Comment: It's really hard to know what you want... I think it's better if you write separate questions, because it seems you have different issues and are trying to address them all here.  For the generic part... the JSON Marshaler is capable to marshal any class, so I'm not sure if you want to create a generic class to use it as a wrapper to marshal any object just using the default TJsonConverter or what (maybe the TResponseObject class name is making it unclear for me).

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do here, but I can make a guess.  For TResponseObject, you want an object that can contain another object and operate on it.  In that case, you probably want to pass it in to the constructor, like so:

```
constructor TResponseObject<T>.Create(value: T);
begin
  FReturnObject := value;
end;
```

Likewise, if you make a GetReturnObject method, it should probably return the value of the FReturnObject field.  (Or you could make the **read** accessor of the property just reference FReturnObject directly.)

```
function TResponseObject<T>.GetReturnObject: T;
begin
  Result := FReturnObject;
end;
```

It's really hard to answer #3 since I don't know what you're trying to do with this, but hopefully my answers to the first two will help you get back on track.  Just remember that generics don't have to be confusing; they're basically just type substitution.  Anywhere you'd use a normal type in a non-generic routine, you can replace it with a `<T>` to create a generic routine, and then substitute any type that fits the constraints for that particular `T`.

Comment: Hi Mason, is it possible to contact you via MSN or Google Talk?

Comment: @Phillip: I'd prefer, if you had further questions, that you post them on here.  That way anyone else who runs across similar issues in the future can benefit from the answers as well.

Comment: Thanks Mason,

Without using generics, I have the following code that converts an object to JSON:

procedure Serialize;
var
  Marshal: TJSONMarshal;
  FileResult: TFileOperationResult;
  V: TJSONValue;
begin
  FileResult := TFileOperationResult.Create;
  FileResult.Success := True;
  FileResult.LastError := 100;

  Marshal := TJSONMarshal.Create(TJSONConverter.Create);
  //Marshal.RegisterConverter(TFileOperationResult, BaseStringsConverter);
  V := Marshal.Marshal(FileResult);
  OutPut := V.ToString;

  FileResult.Free;
  Marshal.Free;
end;

Comment: The output is as follows:

{"type":"uJSonSerializer.TFileOperationResult","id":1,"fields":{"FSuccess":true,"FLastError":100}}

In short, what I am trying to do is pass in any object, and convert it to JSON using Generics.

Comment: When using generics, I am getting the following incorrect result. (I am looking for the result as before).

{"type":"DBXJSONReflect.TJSONConverter","id":1,"fields":{"FRoot":{"type":"DBXJSON.TJSONObject","id":2,"fields":{"FMembers":{"type":"DBXPlatform.TDBXArrayList","id":3,"fields":{"FList":{"type":"Contnrs.TObjectList","id":4,"fields":{"FOwnsObjects":false,"FCount":3,"FCapacity":4}}}},"FOwned":true}},"FStack":{"type":"Generics.Collections.TStack<DBXJSON.TJSONAncestor>","id":5,"fields":{"FCount":8,"FItems":
... etc etc

Very much appreciate your assistance.

Comment: @Philip: Well, I don't know the JSON stuff all that well, but it looks to me like something is serializing your TJSONConverter itself, instead of the object.  Try tracing through the code with the debugger and see if you can figure out where it's going wrong.

Comment: @Philip, comments aren't the best place to ask questions, especially ones with source code in them. Only inline source code formats correctly in comments. You should probably make this a new question so others will notice it.